# get all shape shape property values

Tags: vba, visio

I have some shapes, which include custom property data I would like to extract.
At the moment I do this using a loop what seems to be quite slow. Therfore I hope that there is a possibility to get all the data at once.

Code:

```
For n = 0 To ActiveDocument.Pages(Pages).Shapes.Item(Index).RowCount(visSectionProp) - 1
    x = ActiveDocument.Pages(Pages).Shapes.Item(Index).CellsSRC(visSectionProp, n, visCustPropsValue).Formula
    shape_props(i + shapecount_old, n) = x
Next
```

Does anyone has an idea?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean with "seems to be quite slow"?

Comment: Its the slowest part of my code and I think there must be faster option to solve this.
After collecting the data with the discribed routine, I transfer the data to an Access database. 
Saving and loading the same information from that DB with vba is around 5 times faster than collecting the data out of Visio. So I want to improve performance there

Comment: Reducing the "dot count" of your code can improve performance in some cases - try using a with block to reduce the repetition in your code.

Comment: @TimWilliams actually this wasn't the solution I was thinkig about (I hoped that theres is a shape.function, which can deliver the data much faster). But this really improved the performance a lot! 
I thought 'which' only helps for a more fancy syntax.
Thanks for the hint!

Comment: You can use getformulas, which is much faster. You set an array of SRC’s and shape ids and Visio gives you all the formulas in one call.

Comment: @JonFournier I thought about getformulas. But I don't know how to apply this correctly (what to use for SID_SRCStream() ) to get the information I need. Can you give me an example please?

Comment: msdn has a passable example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/visio-vba/articles/shape-getformulas-method-visio  If you play with that a bit you should get the concept and be able to implement it.